# How can I test my intermittent problem with my Logitech MX Revolution?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, mouse

I'm experiencing a problem where my MX Revolution does a double-click instead of a single click like I intended...I'm using the latest driver from Logitech v 5.10.9 and the Set Point Control Center version is v 6.15.6.

How would I know if it's hardware (IOW a switch malfunctioning in the mouse), software or the wireless connection between "mouse and machine"?

The OS is 32 bit Win7 and the machine is a Dell Latitude D620

Any troubleshooting ideas greatly appreciated.

**Update**
*I ended up finding the receipt...the mouse was over three years old...but Logitech replaced it under warranty anyway with a Performance MX model... **+1 for Logitech**...I just received the new mouse a couple of days ago!!!*

Comment: It's gotta be the switch...tried it on a custom built PC running Win7 64-bit and it still double clicks intermittently when single clicking ...gonna try compressed air...and after that...getting out the screwdriver to take it apart...this should be fun

Comment: Woo hoo!  When in doubt, disassemble!

Comment: Very nice; I'll admit I don't love Logitech's drivers (bloat-city), but I've never had a hardware complaint, and I keep buying their stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the obvious.  How does the switch "feel"?  Is it sticky?  When you click, do you feel it click twice?  Does the phantom double come from only one button, or both (or multiple?)  Has it been subjected to abuse, children or a bath in a sticky substance?

Many driver interfaces (Logitech's included) usually have some sort of monitor applet that lets you watch an animation of the mouse and what inputs are firing in real- or near-realtime.

Comment: The switch feels same as it always has..no change there..I only feel it click once...the phantom double comes from the left mouse button, the most used button so that's what led me to slightly suspect it's a hardware issue...It has not been subjected to any abuse...quite the opposite...it's been well taken care of in it's lifetime...I'll dig around for the monitor applet...PS.it just did it when I clicked the Add Comment button...argghhhh....

Comment: That *really* sounds like a mechanical problem; no matter how much we baby them, things do wear out.  How old is the mouse, and how heavily has it been used?

Comment: It's maybe a little over 18 months old and I would say it's used heavily...I'm a software engineer and I'm at my desk over 40 hrs a week so...although I do probably use the keyboard more than a "normal" Windows user.

Comment: I think all of us that are in "this business" are a little abnormal.  18 months isn't very long; I have a couple of mice 2-3 times that age with equal use/abuse that haven't had problems.  Between pure "at work" mice that see me all week to "at home" mice that sometimes see me working from home and all too often see me wasting time on video games.  Still, it seems unlikely to be software; perhaps try some high-pressure air under the finger surface of the button, maybe there's some grit in the switch...

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

1. If you can, try it on a different computer.  Don't install the Logitech drivers, just plug in the USB cord or wireless dongle and see what happens.  All wireless mice will work to some extent without the drivers.  If it works fine on the other computer, it's something to do with the drivers.
2. If you don't have another computer, try uninstalling the drivers and SetPoint software and see what happens.  If it still happens without any software interfering, it's likely the mouse itself.

May also be helpful to know which Operating System you're using and what kind of computer.

Comment: Good thoughts...I'll try it on another machine _and_ on this machine w/o the Logitech software...I've edited my question to include the OS and the machine brand and model